# cordova type=tel keypad language

Tags: html, cordova

I have a cordova app with an input text field where type=tel. When I click on this field the dialer keypad pops up, only the letters are in Hebrew. I am located in Israel but the phone's locale is set to English. How can I make it open the dialer with english letters?

Thanks.[image]